# How to prevent creating migrations and applying them for specified dbContext in Entity Framework Core 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext

I'm using two db contexts for **read** and **write** side, poinitng to the same db schema.

**ReadDbContext** and **WriteDbContext** have their own **read** and **write** models defined respectively.

Since the relations, table names and finally the database are the same in both of these contexts configuration, only the one of them can scaffold the database.

Is there any way to disable the ability of applying created migrations for specified db conext? Going further, is there a possibility to even disallow the migrations creating?

I tried to add `Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null)` to DbContext constructor, but that doesn't seem to work in EF Core 6.

For better understanding you can checkout the code below.

**ReadDbContext**

```
internal sealed class ReadDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserReadModel> Users => Set<UserReadModel>();
    public DbSet<RoleReadModel> Roles => Set<RoleReadModel>();
    public DbSet<PermissionReadModel> Permissions => Set<PermissionReadModel>();

    public ReadDbContext(DbContextOptions<ReadDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("user-manager");

        var configuration = new ReadConfiguration();

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<UserReadModel>(configuration);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<RoleReadModel>(configuration);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<PermissionReadModel>(configuration);
    }
}
```

**WriteDbContext**

```
internal sealed class WriteDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users => Set<User>();
    public DbSet<Role> Roles => Set<Role>();
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions => Set<Permission>();

    public WriteDbContext(DbContextOptions<WriteDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("user-manager");

        var configuration = new WriteConfiguration();

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<User>(configuration);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Role>(configuration);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Permission>(configuration);
    }
}
```

**ReadConfiguration**

```
internal sealed class ReadConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserReadModel>, IEntityTypeConfiguration<RoleReadModel>,
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<PermissionReadModel>
{
    private readonly ValueConverter<UserNameReadModel, string> _userNameConverter = new(un => un.ToString(), un =>  new UserNameReadModel(un));
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserReadModel> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Users");
        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);

        builder
            .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
            .WithMany(r => r.Users)
            .UsingEntity("UsersRoles");

        builder
            .Property(u => u.Name)
            .HasConversion(_userNameConverter!);
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RoleReadModel> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Roles");
        builder.HasKey(r => r.Id);

        builder
            .HasMany(r => r.Permissions)
            .WithMany(p => p.Roles)
            .UsingEntity("RolesPermissions");
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PermissionReadModel> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Permissions");
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
    }
}
```

**WriteConfiguration**

```
internal sealed class WriteConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>, IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>,
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Permission>
{
    private readonly ValueConverter<UserId, Guid> _userIdConverter = new(u => u.Value, u => u);
    private readonly ValueConverter<RoleId, Guid> _roleIdConverter = new(r => r.Value, r => r);
    private readonly ValueConverter<UserName, string> _userNameConverter = new(un => un.ToString(), un => UserName.Create(un));
    private readonly ValueConverter<RoleName, string> _roleNameConverter = new(rn => rn.ToString(), rn => RoleName.Create(rn));
    private readonly ValueConverter<Email, string> _emailConverter = new(e => e.ToString(), e => Email.Create(e));
    private readonly ValueConverter<Password, string> _passwordConverter = new(p => p.ToString(), p => Password.Create(p));

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Users");
        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);
        builder
            .Property(r => r.Id)
            .HasConversion(_userIdConverter);
        
        builder
            .Property(typeof(UserName), "_name")
            .HasConversion(_userNameConverter)
            .HasColumnName("Name");
        
        builder
            .Property(typeof(Email), "_email")
            .HasConversion(_emailConverter)
            .HasColumnName(nameof(Email));
        
        builder
            .Property(typeof(Password), "_password")
            .HasConversion(_passwordConverter)
            .HasColumnName(nameof(Password));
        
        builder
            .HasMany(typeof(Role), "_roles")
            .WithMany("_users")
            .UsingEntity("UsersRoles");
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Roles");
        builder.HasKey(r => r.Id);
        builder
            .Property(r => r.Id)
            .HasConversion(_roleIdConverter);
        
        builder
            .Property(typeof(RoleName), "_name")
            .HasConversion(_roleNameConverter)
            .HasColumnName("Name");

        builder.HasMany(typeof(Permission), "_permissions");
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Permission> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Permissions");
        builder.Property<Guid>("Id");
        builder.Property<string>("Name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have one dbContext and create custom interfaces to control the interaction with that dbContext?

Comment: *"Going further, is there a possibility to even disallow the migrations creating?"* There is not automatic migration creation in EF Core. If you don't use `Add-Migration` commands for specific context, there won't be migrations for it.

Comment: @IvanStoev I know there is no automatic migration, but I would like to prevent other team members from creating them manually. It is not something obligatory, but if it was possible, I would gladly use it.

Comment: Then the feature you need is called source code control, and has nothing to do with EF Core.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can exclude from migrations:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ApplicationUsers", t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());
}
```

Comment: If there is no option to exclude whole dbContext I will stick to this, thanks.